# Inserting Equations in Pages - Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: shortcut, pages

I use the "Insert > Equation..." feature in Pages quite frequently. Is there a keyboard shortcut to open this box faster than clicking through first "Insert" and then "Equation..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined shortcut is shown as Option & Command & E to enter the equation editor.